# jQuery: trying to show loading gif while div is loading

Tags: jquery

I have a script that isn't working for me - I'm not sure why, but I'm sure I'm not doing something right.

JavaScript

```
<script>
    $('.topslider .orbit-container').hide();
    $('.topslider').html('<img src="img/loading.gif" id="loading" />')

    $(window).bind('load', function() {
        $('.topslider #loading').hide();
        $('.topslider .orbit-container').fadeIn('slow');
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="topslider">
    <div class="orbit-container">
        [content here]
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to hide `div.orbit-container` and show `img#loading` for the time that `div.orbit-container` takes to load, then hide `img#loading` and show `div.orbit-container` once it's loaded. Any help is appreciated!

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9CQ4/96/
1) `div.orbit-container` hides successfully
2) `img#loading` shows successfully
3) `img#loading` hides successfully
4) `div.orbit-container` doesn't fade back in... this is where the problem is.

---

The answer (as stated below) is to replace `.html()` with `.append()`, as in the this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9CQ4/97/

Comment: that fiddle doesnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.html() overwrite inner code, .append() append code to current inner code
SO by .html() you delete your orbit-container

```
$('.topslider .orbit-container').hide(); 
$('.topslider').html('<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" id="loading" />')

$(window).bind('load', function() {
            $('.topslider #loading').hide();
            $('.topslider').html('<div class="orbit-container">CONTENT HERE</div>')
            $('.topslider .orbit-container').fadeIn('slow');
        });
```

or with .append() fcn

```
$('.topslider .orbit-container').hide(); 
$('.topslider').append('<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" id="loading" />')

$(window).bind('load', function() {
            $('.topslider #loading').hide();
            $('.topslider .orbit-container').fadeIn('slow');
        });
```

Comment: The `.orbit-container` div is a pretty big chunk of code, it actually is created with javascript to begin with (it's the orbit slider in foundation). So I need to write the html but I can't erase `.orbit-container`, is there a way to add the img to `.topslider` without erasing everything else in it? I'm not too good with JS, I'm looking into `.append()`

Comment: I edited my answer,use of .append() function, not .html(), might be the solution i think

Comment: I just did the same thing too haha: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9CQ4/97/ aweomse! A year ago I wouldn't have been able to understand this stuff, it's good fun though! Thanks for helping me =)

Comment: updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9CQ4/219/), to see the effect of loading and content appearing thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="topslider">
    <div class="orbit-container">
        CONTENT HERE
    </div>
    <div id="loading" style="display:none;">LOADING</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.topslider .orbit-container').hide();
$('.loading').html('<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />')

$(window).bind('load', function() {
    $('.topslider #loading').hide();
    $('.topslider .orbit-container').fadeIn('slow');
});
```